# Why wouldn't a search from glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) work correctly?

Tags: c++, opengl

I read this page:
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlGetString

> For example, if the extension
>   GL_EXT_pixel_transform_color_table is
>   listed, doing a simple search for
>   GL_EXT_pixel_transform will return a
>   positive whether or not it is defined.

How is that possible since its space separated? Why dont you just put a space after the keyword you're searching for?

For example:

```
char *exts = (char *)glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
if(!strstr(exts, "GL_EXT_pixel_transform ")){ // notice the space!
    // not supported
}
```

I would like to know why this wouldnt work, because for me it does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if the extension you are looking for is listed last? Then it will not be followed by a blank.

Comment: hmm... seriously? im sure i checked this before... but now i checked it again, looks like there is no space...! what the hell were they thinking? oh well. i could just add the space there myself then. or a better just to add them into std::map lol.

Comment: @Rookie: The canonical solution for such problems is to tokenize with a specific separator (a `' '` in this case) and do comparisons on the tokens. The C standard library has `strtok`  for this.

Comment: @datenwol: strtok is a horrible abomination that should never be mentioned, let alone used in C++.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Agreed, but in the case of checking for extensions it's not so bad. `int is_extension_supported(char const *ext){int sup = 0; char *es = strdup(glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)); char *tok = strtok(es, " "); while(tok){ if(!strcmp(ext, tok)){sup = 1; break;} strtok(0, " ");} free(es); return sup; }`

Answer (score 4):

You can tokenise the returned string using space as separator for more reliable search (if you don't want to use the newer API). E.g. with [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tokenizer/index.html):

```
typedef boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;

boost::char_separator<char> sep(" ");
tokenizer tok(static_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)), sep);

if (std::find(tok.begin(), tok.end(), "GL_EXT_pixel_transform") != tok.end()) {
    // extension found
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::find(tok.begin(), tok.end(), "GL_EXT_pixel_transform") != tok.end` instead, you know.

Comment: @ybungalobill: *facepalm* My brain just doesn't work today. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but maybe someone else will find it useful. In case you don't want to use any tokenizing library/class here is a function that scans a string for an exact substring (without the mentioned problem). Also, it almost doesn't use any additional memory (string data is not copied):

```
bool strstrexact(const char *str, const char *substr, const char *delim, const bool isRecursiveCall = 0)
{
    static int substrLen;

    if (!isRecursiveCall)
        substrLen = strlen(substr);

    if (substrLen <= 0)
        return FALSE;

    const char *occurence = strstr(str, substr);

    if (occurence == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    occurence += substrLen;

    if (*occurence == '\0')
        return TRUE;

    const char *nextDelim;
    nextDelim = strstr(occurence, delim);

    if (nextDelim == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    if (nextDelim == occurence)
        return TRUE;

    return strstrexact(nextDelim, substr, delim, TRUE);
}
```

It returns TRUE if the substring was found or FALSE if it wasn't. In my case Here's how I used it:

```
if (strstrexact((const char*) glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS), "WGL_ARB_pixel_format", " ")) {
    // extension is available
} else {
    // extension isn't available
}
```